# Pod <-> compute machine with CPU and RAM?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I am working with containers that contain HTTP-based REST Apis. Each container contains one service.

[This](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/kubernetes-basics/explore/explore-intro/) documentation page says that each pod has a unique IP address, from which I conclude that the service inside each container can be accessed by this IP address but with a specific port. It is also stated that a pod is associated with a storage volume such that all containers have access to it. My first question comes here : **do the containers inside the same pod pick in the same physical memory also when they are run ?**

Reading documentation about pods reminded me of how I used to make multiple services interact with each other on my laptop. I opened them all on my laptop so they have the same IP address (localhost), and I could request one of the services by specifying the port it is listening to. So in my brain, I identified a *pod* to a laptop/a computer.
My second question would be: **is this identification correct or misleading ?**

When I read further the documentation, I find that:

> A node is a worker machine ... and may be ... a physical machine

and that pods run on nodes. Here I am confused. If a node is a worker machine, so a compute machine juste like my laptop, then it has a unique IP address. And this is is incompatible with the fact that nodes run pods and that each pod has it unique IP address. I'm assuming that if a node is a machine, then it has an IP address X, and all "things" inside this machine will also have the same IP address X, including the pods.
So I again ask my second question : **is a pod a compute machine ?**

I think I need to sit down with someone that knows about the Kubernetes API, but not having such guy or girl, I'm trying here while continuing reading the docs!

Answer (score 2):

All valid questions demonstrating an inquisitive mind (not guaranteed in IT these days). To answer your questions:

**1. Do the containers inside the same Pod pick in the same physical memory also when they are run?**

Containers all run on the same Kernel and therefore share the same resources. Unlike VMs there is no virtualization layer isolating them. However, Container processes benefit from **the same memory isolation as any other process running on a Linux kernel**. On top of that, container processes can be limited to use not more than a certain amount of memory and CPU.

**2. Is this identification [Pods are like services running on a Laptop] correct or misleading?**

This identification only holds regarding **networking**: just like on your laptop all Pod containers run in the same network and therefore can address each other with `localhost`. However, unlike on your laptop, **containers within Pods are still isolated from each other**. They have their own file systems and run in separate process namespaces.

**3. Is a Pod a compute machine?**

A compute machine would be hardware (virtual or real) plus a operating system (kernel + applications) in my books. That means **a Pod is not a compute machine**. A Pod is merely a bunch of contained processes sharing a network namespace. In order to run a Pod, you need to provide hardware, Kernel and container runtime aka a K8s cluster.

Regarding networking: K8s worker machines have IP addresses assigned to them that make them addressable within their network or externally. Those IPs don't conflict with IPs assigned to Pods since Pod IPs are **internal IPs**. They are only addressable from within K8s virtual network, i.e. from other Pods within the same K8s cluster.

Comment: Thanks for your thorough answer. I may not have formulated clearly the very first question. I meant is the RAM (hardware) available for a container (before it actually uses a part of it) is the same RAM (hardware) for all containers running in pod ? It seems like it is. And I'm wondering wether the same applies to all containers in a _node_ : they all use the RAM and CPU of the same computing machine (the node). Is this correct ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. If they are deployed to the same worker node, they share the same Kernel and therefore the same hardware. To protect against DOS attacks you will have set resource usage limits.

Comment: after reading about network namespaces and virtual network interfaces on wikipedia and youtube, seems to me like a pod is a network namespace + a virtual network interface created on a node

Comment: Correct, but it is not only that. A pod entails one or several contained and isolated processes, each with their exclusive file system. Containment is done in respect to CPU, RAM and storage usage. Isolation is done not only in terms of network, but also process, IPC and hostname.

Answer (score 1):

Following are the simplistic definitions :

Container : An application which runs in a isolated user space (Note : not kernelspace) with all its dependencies required. so we can consider this as a 'light weight VM' from application perspective. we say 'light weight' because it shares Host OS kernel. we say its a '(light weight)VM' because it contains its own and isolated Process Namespace (Pid) , Network Name Space (net) , Disk NameSpace (mnt) and time (uts).

How can each container have its own IP which different to the Host IP ?  :

- This is possible due the implementation of "Network NameSpace"

Then what is a Pod ?

- Pod is a Kubernetes object which will enable users to run containers. Kubernetes implemented Pod as an abstraction layer to break dependency with CRI (container runtime)

Can Pod multiple containers in them ?

- Yes a POD can have multiple containers. IP is assigned at the pod level . so in case of multicontainer pods they can communicate among each other over localhost interface of the containers.

Is the pod that runs containers a compute machine with ram and cpu ? Is that rather a node ?

- Yes , while creating a container as part of Pods you can assign Ram & CPU  to it . [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-resources-containers/)

It's more about how can a node have an IP address and the pods inside it have other IP addresses ?

- This is possible with combination two linux features Veth interface ( Virtual Ethernet ) and network namespaces . even in a world with out containers we can create multiple veth intefaces in a linus system and assign different IPs to them. so containers leveraged veths of linux and combined them with network namespace to act as a isolated network environment for a container. see this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j_UUnlVC2Ss&ab_channel=KodeKloud)

Please refer following articles :

- https://medium.com/faun/understanding-nodes-pods-containers-and-clusters-778dbd56ade8
- https://www.mirantis.com/blog/multi-container-pods-and-container-communication-in-kubernetes/

Comment: I think it's not much the container definition that confuses me though I am not aware of the low level details such as the pid you mentioned. It's more about how can a node have an IP address and the pods inside it have other IP addresses ? Is the pod that runs containers a compute machine with ram and cpu ? Is that rather a node ?

Comment: @dada i have added little more information to my answers wrt to your questions

Comment: hmm I am reading about virtual ethernet on wikipedia and the video you attached, I think that was the part I was missing; thank you for letting me know about it!

Comment: However, concerning the first question you're answering in your post, from what I understood all containers/rest apis are accessed at the same IP address, one can distinguish between them with ports

Comment: @confused_genius the video says that "network namespace + virtual network interface" is the mechanism used for containers running in a computer, and you said that it is the mechanism used for pods running in a computer. So does this mean that we can run a container in a namespace (the pod), while the container is itself a namespace ? So it's like creating a namespace in a namespace 

Comment: @dada To fully understand this, you have to start differentiating Linux namespaces. The only namespace that the containers in a Pod have in common is the network. Other than that they run in separate namespaces (process, IPC, UTS). The have separate file systems and separate resource limits.

Comment: In the case of pods running one single container each, can we say that pod = container = network + pid + ipc + uts namespace (+ perhaps other kinds of namespaces) ? And in case there are multiple containers in a pod, there is one network namespace per pod, and multiple pid + ipc + uts namespaces (one per container)

Comment: Well actually, may be it's simpler to think of it this way. We have a machine, we create many pid, network, ipc, uts namespaces. The set of processes sharing the same namespaces is a container. So we can associate a container to a set of pid, network, ipc, uts namespaces. However for the network namespaces, we can decide that N containers belong to the same network namespace. So until now, there is only the machine and containers (sets of namespaces of certain kinds). Then, we define a pod as being a set of containers belonging to the same network namespace....

Comment: ....perhaps with the additional constraint that each container do not share the other namespaces with the other containers

Comment: I should add to this definition resource management (cgroups)